# Add a second auto-increment field and allow duplicates

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have an EXISTING table which has a primary key called ID and 6 other fields relating to invoicing.  I need to insert the values from an old table and insert all the values into the new, but recently created table.  The old table has the invoice numbers listed, and sometimes the invoice numbers have duplicates.  I need this new column I'm trying to create, called `invoice_id` to AUTO_INCREMENT when there is no value inserted for future values which will be inserted, and to ALLOW DUPLICATES on the existing values AND future values.  When there is no value inserted, it needs to auto_increment.

```
ID (primary) || invoice_ID (needs to auto_increment AND allow duplicates) || other colums
1            || 1
2            || 2
3            || 2
4            || 3
```

I've tried a few commands and this is what happens:

```
ALTER TABLE  `invoices` ADD  `invoice_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER  `ID` ,
ADD PRIMARY KEY (  `facture` )
```

RESULT:

```
MySQL said: 
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be 
defined as a key
```

ALSO TRIED:

```
ALTER TABLE  `invoices` ADD  `invoice_ID` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT AFTER  `ID` ,
ADD KEY (  `invoice_ID` ) ,
ADD INDEX (  `invoice_ID` )
```

RESULT:

```
#1075 - Incorrect table definition; **there can be only one auto column** and it must 
be defined as a key
```

I also tried a few different options like not adding as primary key of course, but seems as soon as I add the auto_increment request, it makes my query "AS PRIMARY KEY".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with a trigger. Here's an example.

So you have your old table:

```
drop table if exists invoices_old;
create table invoices_old (
invoice_ID int,
another_column int
);

insert into invoices_old values
(1,11),
(2,12),
(2,13),
(3,14),
(4,15),
(5,16),
(6,17),
(6,18),
(7,19);
```

which you want to insert into your new table:

```
drop table if exists invoices_new;
create table invoices_new (
id int not null auto_increment,
invoice_ID int default null, /*it's important here to have a default value*/
another_column int,
primary key (id)
);
```

You copy your data probably like this:

```
insert into invoices_new (invoice_ID, another_column)
select invoice_ID, another_column 
from invoices_old;
```

Now that you have your data in the new table, you create a trigger on the new table to simulate an auto_increment column.

```
drop trigger if exists second_auto_inc;
delimiter $$
create trigger second_auto_inc before insert on invoices_new 
for each row
begin
set @my_auto_inc := NULL;
select max(invoice_ID) into @my_auto_inc from invoices_new;
set new.invoice_ID = @my_auto_inc + 1;
end $$
delimiter ;
```

Now when you insert more rows into the new table

```
insert into invoices_new (another_column)
select 20 union all select 21 union all select 22;
```

and have a look at your table

```
select * from invoices_new;
```

it works.

Result:

```
id  invoice_ID  another_column
1   1           11
2   2           12
3   2           13
4   3           14
5   4           15
6   5           16
7   6           17
8   6           18
9   7           19
16  8           20
17  9           21
18  10          22
```

You're probably wondering why in the real auto_increment column the IDs jump from 9 to 16. There was a good post about it here on SO recently, but I can't find it right now. Anyway, that's nothing you have to worry about. Auto_increment is there to ensure uniqueness, not a gapless sequence.

Comment: Thank you fancyPants, that must have been time consuming to answer this question and I haven't gone through all of it yet, but I read, and re-read it and this is much more advanced than what I know.  I'm very pleased at the description and comments in your answer.  So I started going through your answer step-by-step and so far, everything is working perfectly fine.  Now i just need to get familiar with this _trigger_ command you posted above and that whole section of code.  Again, thank you for your time.  Oh, I need 15 reputation to be able to vote up your answer, so will be done ASAP.

Comment: Glad to hear that. If you have more questions, feel free to ask. And btw, though you can't upvote yet, you can accept the answer :)